# How to fix cell format as a date (with YYYYMMDD format) and texts are not allowed

Tags: excel, vba, date, validation

I want to fix the format of a range of cells as date with this formatting: "YYYYMMDD" and no texts are supposed to be allowed. 
I also want this formatting to hold true if a user inserts a new row below "G12". Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
The code is located in a command button in my sheet1. There was no error at all. But if my value in the cell are texts then it doesnt throw up an error like its supposed to.

This is the code I tried to run but its not working

```
  With Range("G12") 
       if Len(.value) <> 8 Then
       MsgBox "Date format must be in YYYYMMDD"

       If not IsDate(.value) then
        Msgbox "Date of Birth is a Mandotory field"

       End If
       End If

  End With
```

**Updated**

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F13")) Is Nothing Then

   If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And Not cel.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd" Then
            MsgBox "Date format must be in YYYYMMDD"
            cel.Value = ""
            Exit Sub
       Else: cel.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
       End If
   End With

 End If
```

Comment: Where is this code located? And by not working, do you mean: A) that you've placed a breakpoint, but the breakpoint was never reached, or B) the breakpoint was reached, but the code didn't cause the desired result? (Could also be tested with `Debug.Print` instead of a breakpoint.)

Comment: @Mistella its located in a command button in my sheet1. There was no error but if my value in the cell are texts it doesnt throw up an error like its supposed to

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Validation to require that the column holds a date, and set the numberformat of the column to "YYYYMMDD". Any row inserted will inherit those rules in teh target column.

Comment: I tried that with date validation (by using data validation in Excel) but they asked for a range of dates to be inputed but I dont want to restrict my range of dates for users

Comment: then set the range as 1/1/1900 to 31/12/2099

Comment: I need the format to be specifically YYYYMMDD but data validation doesnt seem to accept such an input for validation. I tried typing 19000101 and 30001231. The error says "The date you entered for the Start Date is invalid".

Comment: The date in data validation needs to be entered in a conventional fashion. The number format will then change the display of that date to yyyyMMDD - bear in mind that in excel a date is simply a number - how humans see that date is a function of display.

Answer (score 0):

**I think for this particular purpose you should make use of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`**

Like put this code on in the Sheet where you are working

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

For Each cel In Target
If cel.Column = 7 Then

      With cel
           If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And Not cel.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd" Then
                MsgBox "Date format must be in YYYYMMDD"
                cel.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
           Else: cel.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
           End If
      End With

End If
Next
End Sub
```

This should make every cell in the G column with your required Format. You can include more checks if you want.

Comment: Mikku, I tried your code but it doesnt work so I tried the updated code that i posted above^ but it doesnt work either cause no errors were passed if the conditions were not met